# Java Servlet NumberFormatException

Tags: java, exception, servlets, number-formatting

I'm getting a NumberFormatException in my code that should update an SQL-column. The exception references to the id being null, when I'm trying to resolve it from a string to an int. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since the code I've used has worked on insert and remove clauses beforeHere's the error and code, if anyone can help.

Stacktrace:

```
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
    at control.EditScoreServlet.doPost(EditScoreServlet.java:34)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Code:

```
    package control;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import model.Score;
    import model.dao.ScoreDAO;

    @WebServlet("/editscore")
    public class EditScoreServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/editscore.jsp").forward(req, resp);

        }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

            try {
                String name = req.getParameter("name");
                String strDiff= req.getParameter("diff");
                int diff= Integer.parseInt(strDiff);
                String song = req.getParameter("song");
                String grade = req.getParameter("grade");
                String score = req.getParameter("score");
                String groove = req.getParameter("groove");
                int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));

                Score score = new Score(id, name, diff, song, grade, score, groove);
                ScoreDAO scoredao = new ScoreDAO();
                System.out.println(score.toString());

                boolean updateSuccess= scoredao.editScore(tulos);

                if (updateSuccess)
                    resp.sendRedirect("/listscores");
                else {
                    req.setAttribute("message", "An error occurred when updating a score");
                    req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/actionreport.jsp").forward(req, resp);
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: value for id is coming as null. Please check if you are passing id in request.

Answer (score 0):

See if any of these help you:

- Do something in catch block for NumberFormatException
- maybe add a method which does parseInt, and returns a default in case of parse-failures
- put a null-check before calling parseInt()